# How to set watch on Kubernetes deployments?

Tags: kubectl

I'm using this statement to set a watch on Kubernetes for deployments, but can't get it to register sucessfully:

```
kubeClient.AppsV1().Deployments("default").Watch(v1.ListOptions{})
```

It causes this error message:

```
Failed to register watch for Deployment resource: the server could not 
find the requested resource (get deployments.apps)
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot yet tell you why, however the following statements *do* work:

```
kubeClient.AppsV1beta1().Deployments("default").Watch(v1.ListOptions{})
```

and

```
kubeClient.AppsV1beta2().Deployments("default").Watch(v1.ListOptions{})
```

FWIW, I'm running minikube version: v0.24.1